# Finding all differentiable functions that satisfy an equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

I have tried to solve a problem but it seems I have made a mistake and I don't know where. 
The problem: Find all differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the following condition: $f \circ f = f$.

My approach: $f \circ f = f \implies (f' \circ f)f'=f' \implies f'(x)=0$ or $(f' \circ f)(x)=1$. If $f$ is invertible then we can muliply both sides by the inverse and get that $f(x)=x$. If $f'(f(x))=1$ how can we continue.

We also have to find $f(x)=x$ as a solution. I have tried using the differential notation but things got even messier: $\frac{df(f(x))}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}$. Using the chain rule, i.e.: $\frac{df(g(x))}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$ we obtain $\frac{df}{df}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}$, which is just $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dx}$.

In the meantime, I have found a way to prove that if $f(x)$ is not constant, then $f(x)=x$, but I am not sure whether it is rigurous or not. 
Firstly suppose $f(x) \neq x$. Then $f(x) < x$ or $f(x) > x$. Assume $f(x) > x$. Therefore, there exists $a : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, a(x) > 0$, such that
$f(x)=x+a(x)$. From the definition of the limit, $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(f(x)+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+a(x)+h)-x-a(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x+a(x)+h+a(x+a(x)+h)-x-a(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h+a(x+h+a(x))}{h}$$
The last limit can exist if $\lim_{h \to 0}a(x+h+a(x))=0$, but $a(x)$ is defined to be stictly positive. Analogously, for $f(x)<x$.

Comment: Suppose domain and co-domain of $f$ are coherent. Then $f'(f(x))=1 \forall x\in D(f) \Rightarrow f'(y)=1 \forall y\in E(f) \Rightarrow f(y)=y+C \forall y\in E(f)$. Then one can check what value of $C$ makes if $f(x)=x+C$ consistent with initial equation before differentiating.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but one more application of the chain rule gets you $f''(f(x))=0$ or $f'(x)=0$ , so you get for all x,  one of $f'(x),f'(f(x)), or f''(f(x))$ is 0.

Comment: I don't think that your proof works. If $f$ is not the identity function then possibly $f(x) < x$ for some $x$, and $f(x) > x$ for another $x$. So you cannot conclude that $f(x) = x+a(x)$ with some function which is positive (or negative) everywhere.

Comment: The constant functions satisfy the equation in the OP too.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu what does it mean that 2 sets are coherent. I have googled it and i didn't find many informations.

Comment: @Shthephathord23: It was translation mistake, I've meant each of these sets is connected, that is the same as interval for 1D. Supposal is correct because $D(f)=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = f(\Bbb R)$ be the image of the function. Then $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in A$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $A$ is connected, i.e. an interval. $A$ is also closed because it is equal to the set $\{ x \mid f(x) = x \}$. Therefore $A$ is one of the following:

1. $A = \Bbb R$,
2. $A = (-\infty, b]$ with some $b \in \Bbb R$,
3. $A = [a, b]$ with some $a, b \in \Bbb R$, $a\le b$,
4. $A = [a, \infty)$ with some $a \in \Bbb R$.

In case 2 we have $f(x) = x$ for $x \le b$, and $f(x) \le b$ for $x > b$. Then $f$ would not be differentiable at $b$, so this case is not possible.

Similarly, case 4 is not possible because then $f$ would not be differentiable at $a$, and case 3 is not possible if $a < b$.

So the only possible cases are $A= \Bbb R$ or $A = \{ a \}$. This shows that $f$ is either the identity function on $\Bbb R$, or constant.